# How to import or use AWS SDK in Gatling

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, performance-testing, gatling

I'm trying to do performance testing of a service which hits a couple of AWS endpoints. We have a JMeter script to perform that testing. But recently we came to know Gatling can scale more. So I'm trying to convert my JMeter script to Gatling script. There is a point where I need to read the private key. For that, I need to use AWS SDK. In JMeter, I just copied AWS-SDK jar file into lib folder and it worked. But I'm not sure how I need to use AWS SDK for Gartling. Can any of you have an idea about this stuff? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Gatling is Scala based. Scala is JVM based - hence, interoperable with Java:

> The standard Scala backend is a Java VM. Scala classes are Java
>   classes, and vice versa. You can call the methods of either language
>   from methods in the other one. You can extend Java classes in Scala,
>   and vice versa.

[from here](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/faq/4)

So what you need - is to add the AWS SDK dependencies to the project you build with Gatling just like you do to any other Java/Scala lib.

There are TONS of guidlines over the Internet (and SOF in particular), depending on the build tool you use to manage your project.